# SQL query to find the students in one course

Tags: mysql, sql

There are three tables

Students, Courses and Registration

```
  Students has id, name columns

  Courses has also course.id, course.name
```

and there is third table joining the Students and Courses table

```
Registration : stu_id, course_id
```

One Student can take one or many courses.

I would like to find the name of Students registered in only one course.

Comment: Have you tried something - like reading a manual or browsing some "learn SQL" websites? Then you could attempt a query and if it doesn't work, show it to us and we might be able to help. We aren't here to do your work for you. Perhaps you could use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to experiment and learn!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT S.id, S.name
FROM students S
INNER JOIN registration R ON S.id = R.stu_id
GROUP BY S.id, S.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Like below:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN registration r ON s.id = r.stu_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(r.course_id) = 1
```

Comment: won't `left join` also include students who are not in any course ?

Comment: No, in case of a `left join` you'll also get a row for students not enrolled in any course and result will include them also because of `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

Comment: @snyder Yes, you're right, have to change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(r.course_id)` when using `left join`.

Comment: But why using an Outer join at all when an Inner join already returns the requested result set? Just to make it less efficient? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.*
from (
    select r.stu_id stu_id
    from Registration r
    group by r.stu_id
    having count(*) == 1) ra
join Students s on s.id = ra.stu_id;
```

This one is more efficient.

It's unlikely that your schema has null fields. Therefore, it doesn't matter which kind of join, inner or left, you use.